# While and Do loops not working in PHP

Tags: php

I keep getting an error in my code. the error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'do' (T_DO)

I don't know why, it does this for the while tOo, it's the same error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_while)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home | Learning PHP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $x = 2
      do {
        echo "hi there<br>";
        $x++;
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$x = 2` missing `;` in the end.

Comment: Please, make sure that you __know__ that every php line ends with `;`

Comment: Please, check the manual for proper [do..while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) syntax.

Comment: I just noticed $x =2 was missing a ;

Comment: You've noticed or you've been told twice? I hope _you_ notice the wrong `do..while` syntax too, then.

Comment: Also you don't have loop terminating condition- you need either `while($something) {}` or `do {} while($something)` or `while (true) {if ($something) break;}`